# LINK Error when trying to use OpenSSL evp aes 256 c++

Tags: c++, hyperlink, openssl, aes

i have a lot of LINK error when i'm trying to use the evp aes encryption template code from OpenSSL documentation : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

I have this type of error when i try to compile :

> libcrypto.lib(b_sock.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__ioctlsocket@12 référencé dans la fonction _BIO_socket_ioctl
>
> libcrypto.lib(b_sock.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__getsockname@12 référencé dans la fonction _BIO_sock_info

I include my lib file (libcrypto.lib) and all headers files.
Other code without evp work.

I'm developping on Clion with Visual Studio compiler (C++ 17)

Comment: try using vckg(https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those missing symbols are provided by the windows `ws2_32` library. This is documented, for example, at the bottom of [the documentation page of the `ioctlsocket` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-ioctlsocket). To resolve those symbols, you have to add `ws2_32.lib` as a dependency to your project.

You may have to add more libraries, as briefly mentioned in the OpenSSL note [`NOTES.WIN`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1n/NOTES.WIN#L132-L134).